# Show status of `For` loop to user

Tags: reactjs, loops, asynchronous, react-redux

I have an action which will take quite some time to complete. It will be looping through an array with over 250k entries. With each entry it will be doing some logic. I want to inform the user of the actions progress, which would be:

```js
let progress = (i / array.length) * 100
```

How can I add this to redux store or components state so that I can communicate the current progress in the UI?

I tried dispatching an action (as you can see below) which updates the stores progress with the current iterator but the reducer only executes when the for loop is created.

```js
    export const generateKeyMap = (mapFrom, mapTo) => {
      return async (dispatch) => {
        await dispatch(startGeneration()); <-- This only runs when I use a setTimeout for the following action.
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(buildKeyMap(mapFrom, mapTo));
        }, 100);
      };
    };
    
    export const buildKeyMap = (mapFrom, mapTo) => {
      return async (dispatch) => {
        let keyMap = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < mapFrom.length; i++) {
          await dispatch(reportProgress(i)); // <-- This does not update in store until for loop is done.
            let randomIndex = randomIntFromInterval(0, mapTo.length - 1);
            let key = mapFrom[i].toString();
            let value = mapTo[randomIndex].toString();
            Object.assign(keyMap, { [key]: value });
            mapTo.splice(randomIndex, 1);     
        }
          await dispatch(stopGeneration());
          return { type: actionTypes.DELIVERKEYMAP, payload: keyMap };
        }
      };
```

Comment: A possible (and simple) option would be to batch your list, eg split the 250k items into 100 lists of 2500 and then just update after each list has been processed.

Comment: I really like this concept. I will look into implementing this idea.